# Powershell UAC bypass failing on scheduled task

Tags: powershell, exploit

When running the script (outlined on Hak5 video attached) it fails on the schtasks portion

trying run the script by command and in the powershell debugger fails with the error "schtasks.exe : ERROR: The filename, directory name.... is incorrect"  I've added a "?" to the end of the file which then prompts for the following: "Supply values for the following parameters: FilterScript:" yet per the video (shown below) the script still does not create the c:\Windows\uacbypass directory

video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C9GfMfFjhYI

code:
https://forums.hak5.org/topic/45439-powershell-real-uac-bypass/

Comment: What is the value of the env variable in the registry after you attempt to run it? `Get-ItemPropertyValue "HKCU:\Environment" windir`

Comment: I tried running the Get-ItemPropertyValue command in powershell (after running the ps1 file) and it says Get-ItemPropertyValue not recognized as a cmdlet,function etc

Answer (score 2):

Not all cmdlets are available on all OS and or PowerShell versions, by design.

Get-ItemPropertyValue is on Win10 running PSv5,

```
(Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_OperatingSystem).Caption
$PSVersionTable
Get-Command -Name 'Get-ItemPropertyValue' | Format-Table -AutoSize

# Results

Microsoft Windows 10 Pro

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.17763.316
PSEdition                      Desktop      
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.1.17763.316}
BuildVersion                   10.0.17763.316
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1


CommandType Name                  Version Source                         
----------- ----                  ------- ------                         
Cmdlet      Get-ItemPropertyValue 3.1.0.0 Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
```

but if you tried this on WS2012R2 running PSv4, it is not there, as an example

```
(Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_OperatingSystem).Caption
$PSVersionTable
Get-Command -Name 'Get-ItemPropertyValue' | Format-Table -AutoSize

# Results

Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      4.0
WSManStackVersion              3.0
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
BuildVersion                   6.3.9600.19170
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2    

Get-Command : The term 'Get-ItemPropertyValue' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, ...
```

Secondly, depending on what OS you are on, for windir the are things to consider. See this Q&A below.

[WINDIR environment variable resolves to %SystemRoot% and not C:\windows](https://superuser.com/questions/476965/windir-environment-variable-resolves-to-systemroot-and-not-c-windows)

Even with the above, you still have to be admin on the box for this to work.

Comment: Worth adding that you can easily update Powershell on eg. Server 2012 R2 to 5.1 by installing Windows Management Framework 5.1.

Comment: Agreed, but the was not my point. Many folks new to this, make assumptions that all PowerShell is the same, and we know that is not the case. You can install v5x of various Win clients, but one has to remember of have permission to do so and even if your did, each OS and what's usable in v5x is still a bit different.